# Coordinates and Field values

Tags: yt-project

Consider I have load a dataset as follows:

```
ds = yt.load('pltxxx')
```

The dataset includes the following fields
density, mag_vort, tracer, x_velocity, y_velocity

One can simply plot the mag_vort which is the magnitude of vorticity in 2D domain in this case, by means of:

```
slc = yt.SlicePlot(ds, 'z', 'mag_vort')
```

If I want to export the x-cooridnates, y-coordinates and vorticity_magnitude in the txt file (or numpy array) or plot it via matplotlib scatter plot

```
plt.scatter(x_coor, y_coor, c=mag_vort)
```

Is there an easy way to extract those information from dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a data object (in this case we use the `all_data` data object) to access the field values for the `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'mag_vort'` fields:

```
ad = ds.all_data()
x = ad['x']
y = ad['y']
mag_vort = ad['mag_vort']
```

The arrays you get back from accessing a data object are `YTArray` instances. `YTArray` is a subclass of numpy's `ndarray` that has units attached.

Before you pass these arrays to matplotlib, convert them to whichever units you want to do the plot in, then cast them to numpy arrays:

```
x_plot = np.array(x.to('km'))
y_plot = np.array(y.to('km'))
plt.scatter(x_plot, y_plot, c=np.array(mag_vort))
```

Comment: just minor edit to my question and correct answer: the keyword in plt.scatter is c = np.array(mag_vort) instaed of color=np.array(mag_vort). My bad.